# actionscript equivilent to php explode

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, explode

I have this url for example

/softwarename/object/display?ObjRef=//Sitename/100.AI1

I am wanting to write a script in actionscript that dynamically takes the user to the URl depending on their 'Sitename' and the ID the end as seen in the example '100.AI1'.

Hopefully I can get some help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Actionscript equivalent to PHP [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) would be [String.split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29)

The function signatures are almost identical, and only differ because AS3 is object oriented.

```
var url:String = "/softwarename/object/display?ObjRef=//Sitename/100.AI1";
var results:Array = url.split("ObjRef=//");
var variables:Array = results[1].split("/");
var sitename:String = variables[0];
var id:String = variables[1];
```

Or just using a [regular expression](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html):

```
var url:String = "/softwarename/object/display?ObjRef=//Sitename/100.AI1";
var regex:RegExp = /.*ObjRef=\/\/(.*)\/(.*)/;
var regexResult:Object = regex.exec(url);
var sitename:String = regexResult[1];
var id:String = regesResult[2];
```